# Update new git repository version in existing project

Tags: android, git, repository

I have Android project clone based on git repository with different package name, now the repository updated to new version, how i can to updated this file in my project without make damage?

Comment: what happens if you just do the `git pull`, that should update the file to the latest version. You don't want to have two version files?

Answer (score 0):

You can Check on the commit history in the updated version of the app and make those changes to the old version of the app you already have.
commit history can be found in the top left.

[Commit Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWnEz.jpg)

Also you can get those commit Ids from the commit history available in the repositories and use *git diff* and *git log* commands to get the changes done for that particular commit.

Comment: This is not the real answer to the question asked my OP. However, this is more or less the comment.

Comment: (update) the problem i have cloned repository with no git file(dont know how, its customer project), and i need to update to the latest version of the repository